# Suggestions for better oop designs with real example (file services)

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns

I'm watching Uncle Bob to improve code maintainability and readability.

I've built a system in which can upload various file formats. Bellow I've posted the pdf one.

The below code works perfect but I need help if there is a way to improve code design and quality.

Any suggestion is welcome.

I use an abstract class `FileServices`:

```
abstract class FileServices
{
    protected $file;
    protected $fileName;

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->fileName = pathinfo($this->file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $this->setNewFileNameIfExist();
        $this->saveToDB();
        $this->saveToServer();
    }

    public function saveToServer()
    {
        $path = $this->path;
        $realNameWithExtension = $this->fileName  . $this->fileExtension;
        Storage::put($path . $realNameWithExtension, File::get($this->file));
    }

    abstract function saveToDB();
    abstract function setNewFileNameIfExist();
}
```

And `PDF` child class:

```
class PDF extends FileServices
{
    protected $fileExtension = '.pdf';
    protected $path = 'public/pdf/';

    public function saveToDB()
    {
        $newFile = new \App\PDF();
        $newFile->title = $this->fileName . $this->fileExtension;
        $newFile->save();
    }

    public function setNewFileNameIfExist()
    {
        $counter = 0;
        $realName = $this->fileName;
        $allPDF = \App\PDF::all();
        foreach ($allPDF as $pdf) {
            if($pdf->title === $this->fileName . $this->fileExtension) {
                while($pdf->title === $this->fileName . $this->fileExtension) {
                    $this->fileName = $realName . '(' . $counter . ')';
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the client:

```
$file = $request->file('pdf');
new PDF($file);
```

Many thanks to @tim for his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Protected Field vs Getter and setter**

I prefer to not access fields directly, because it's difficult to use and not very flexible.

When I need to implement a new fileservice, I just need to *know* that I need to define a field called `fileExtension`. If you do not thoroughly document this, implementing new services in the future will be a pain (and even with documentation it's not ideal, as nobody really reads it anyways).

The second problem is that I can only define a string as file extension. What if I want to create an image file service, that allows the uploading of jpg and png files? I would need to dynamically set `fileExtension`, and the only place I could do that is in `saveToDB` or `setNewFileNameIfExist`, neither of which should really be responsible (and even though it may work right now, it may easily break once you change your base `FileServices` class).

It would be a lot better to just add an abstract getter for the file extension.

The same problem exists with `path` as well, and also works the other way around: in `PDF` you work directly on `fileName`, instead of using some setter method.

**Field location**

It is odd that you store the `filename` in `FileServices`, but the `fileExtension` and `path` in `PDF`. Just put them all in `FileServices` to simplify things.

**File class**

You may also consider creating a `File` class, which could hold `file`, `fileName` and `fileExtension`, as they all belong together. It may also contain common functions such as the one to get a filename (without extension).

**Various Store Methods**

I think that it is not ideal to have `saveToDB` and `saveToServer` in your base service. What if I only want to save the file in the database, but not the server?

Instead, I would have a generic, abstract `storeFile` function in `FileServices`.

**Need for abstract `FileServices`?**

Of course, if you follow the advise above, it's not clear that `FileServices` is actually needed as an abstract class. The only thing it does is provide a function to get the name of a file (which may as well be a utility function in some file utility class, as it is likely used elsewhere as well), and a function to save a file to the server (which is really just a call to a different function.)

If you expect more common functionality in the future, this isn't really a problem, otherwise you may consider changing the abstract class to an interface.

**Misc**

- the `PDF` class isn't really a PDF, but a specific kind of file service, so `PDFFileService` would be a better name.
- I prefer constructors to not do the actual work. It seems unclean, and the resulting calling code looks wrong. Reading `new PDF($file)`, I would assume that a new object was created, but not that anything else was actually done. Something like `new PDF($file)->store()` would read more logical to me.
- Your variable names are not consistent with what you consider `real` names. In `saveToServer` it's actually the new file name, in `setNewFileNameIfExist`, it's the original file name.

Comment: if you have time check out my new code codepad.org/SHmYAYwv it was builded keeping your suggestions

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris Not a full review, but some suggestions: 1) `File::setX`: these should be private and *should* actually be called in the constructor (they actually construct the object by setting the required fields; without it, the object is incomplete). This would also simplify how you use the class. 2) a file service isn't really a type of a file, and shouldn't extend it, but work on a `File` object. 3) I actually liked that a FileService defines the types of extensions it allows. Now it is too generic, and would also allow the upload of non-PDF files (eg .php).

Comment: 4) You didn't post `PDF`, that's likely to be interesting as well 5) `PDFFileService` is empty, so not really needed. If you use some of the suggestions, please feel free to post a follow-up question here. I'm sure other people have suggestions as well.

Comment: After many tries I did the follow: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138434/is-there-a-better-approach-using-oop-to-store-file-in-various-formats. I think is much better